# ActiveX not loading under Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website which embeds ActiveX (*.CAB file) using the object tag:

```
<object codeBase="..." classId="..." VIEWASTEXT />
```

However when the website is opened through Selenium the ActiveX doesn't load which prevents me from testing this site. This happens both in IE 9 and IE 10 with Selenium 2.44.0 RemoteWebDriver.
The site works fine if the browser was NOT initialized by Selenium WebDriver.

Does WebDriver by default disables ActiveX loading? How do I enable it back? Do I need to set some additional capabilities?

This is how the RemoteWebDriver is initialized in my case:

```
var dc = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumAddr, dc, url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out 64bit IEDriverServer was loading the 64bit version of the browser and the ActiveX in question doesn't work on 64bit. 
Using 32bit IEDriverServer has solved the problem.